# iReport / JasperReport saving in pdf produces thousand of pages

Tags: jasper-reports

As the title explains, I am creating a Java application that produces a one page report with iReport plugin for NetBeans.

When I run the program the report is produced correctly, I see one page, but when I save to pdf and I open it, it has 11202 pages inside!

I post my jrxml, maybe it can help (note: the details section is now empty, it does the same moving stuff from footpage to details)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="null" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="830" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8cc12745-3ab6-488e-996b-0402135c9199">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="96"/>
    <parameter name="data" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\GreenTable\\src\\pokersoftware\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[Select GuadagnoLordo, GuadagnoNettoBarTorneo,GuadagnoNettoTorneo, GuadagnoNettoBar, IncassoBar, Rake, SpecialSeat, FeeSitandGo, Cavalli, VarieNette, PersonaleBar, GettoneSerata, PersonaleSala, GuadagnoNettoBarTorneo, EuroClassifica, RientriGioco, RientriCash, RientriBar, OneShot, Tesseramento, Mance, Gilet, Slot1, Slot2, Slot3, EuroClassificaPagati, MancePagate, Bollette, Spese1, Spese2, Spese3, Spese4, VarieLorde, GiocoDD, BarDD, CashDD, Note, TotaleCassa, TotaleEuroClassifica, TotaleMance, TotaleSlot
From Serate, Cassa, EuroClassifica, Slot, Mance
Where DescrizioneData = $P{data}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="GuadagnoLordo" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="GuadagnoNettoBarTorneo" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="GuadagnoNettoTorneo" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="GuadagnoNettoBar" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="IncassoBar" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Rake" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="SpecialSeat" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="FeeSitandGo" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Cavalli" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="VarieNette" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="PersonaleBar" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="GettoneSerata" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="PersonaleSala" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="EuroClassifica" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="RientriGioco" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="RientriCash" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="RientriBar" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="OneShot" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Tesseramento" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Mance" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Gilet" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Slot1" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Slot2" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Slot3" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="EuroClassificaPagati" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="MancePagate" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Bollette" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Spese1" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Spese2" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Spese3" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Spese4" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="VarieLorde" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="GiocoDD" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="BarDD" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="CashDD" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Note" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TotaleCassa" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="TotaleEuroClassifica" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="TotaleMance" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="TotaleSlot" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="52" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="95" y="10" width="165" height="35" uuid="075094d9-bc38-4eaa-8c34-808f2a375243"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="24" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Report Serata]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="275" y="10" width="100" height="35" uuid="bf267202-3edd-4a0f-a742-1cc10d570ce7"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="24" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{data}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="104" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="32" width="197" height="20" uuid="38a14aed-0fe3-49ea-ad41-b378591a314d"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{GuadagnoNettoBarTorneo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="72" width="159" height="20" uuid="b6cee7fb-3bf4-4a81-b3ff-ef3ddd748ddd"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[GUADAGNO NETTO TORNEO ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="52" width="149" height="20" uuid="87ecd852-de31-49e3-965b-3180d8fe5a38"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{GuadagnoNettoBar}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="52" width="159" height="20" uuid="0e256ee8-c442-4377-a8b9-2149841a7627"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[GUADAGNO NETTO BAR]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="72" width="160" height="20" uuid="72814694-893f-4522-9236-4be87d943762"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{GuadagnoNettoTorneo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="12" width="122" height="20" uuid="1edb458d-0ae5-4094-9c83-9bfe4ec7fcef"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[GUADAGNO LORDO]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="32" width="200" height="20" uuid="8df46dc2-9a5b-4c51-b0a6-793f609782b1"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[GUADAGNO NETTO (bar + gioco)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="12" width="149" height="20" uuid="c21bac4a-09e4-45f7-acad-9f59deb3510d"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{GuadagnoLordo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="397" y="12" width="80" height="20" uuid="700cd3a0-52c0-4dd3-8ff0-1d34cc850b48"/>
                <text><![CDATA[CASSA]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="397" y="32" width="80" height="20" uuid="389c7fd2-be82-4b62-87c9-a636fbf69ca7"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Progressivo Euro]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="397" y="52" width="80" height="20" uuid="14ce667e-10f9-44ae-88ab-3115a9d91395"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Progressivo Mance]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="397" y="72" width="80" height="20" uuid="458234d3-0893-4430-8453-736bd297bc8e"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Progressivo Slot]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="477" y="12" width="78" height="20" uuid="f99a5a92-8e63-46b0-8db9-0e29b2fda680"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TotaleCassa}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="477" y="32" width="78" height="20" uuid="488d53f7-2dfe-4962-b9d2-0405201ece30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TotaleEuroClassifica}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="477" y="52" width="78" height="20" uuid="988c4e1c-b0fe-48b6-ae3f-7b10db0df9ad"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TotaleMance}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="477" y="72" width="78" height="20" uuid="7bf4988c-ce57-452d-b054-86e4152e5a4a"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TotaleSlot}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="221" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="286" y="179" width="100" height="20" uuid="7bef313e-c70c-4cf8-aec1-0406c59334ce"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Varie Nette]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="334" y="109" width="100" height="20" uuid="c8df9beb-ffe7-4256-98ca-7b81b49f2257"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Personale Bar]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="334" y="89" width="100" height="20" uuid="fc9c3380-7b8d-4dc8-9e47-2b55189dd721"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Personale Sala]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="434" y="109" width="100" height="20" uuid="af7caf17-eca3-4bba-ac50-816f05ac8a66"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PersonaleBar}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="334" y="129" width="100" height="20" uuid="e2e50604-7508-437c-956c-5967251ae088"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Gettone Serata]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="434" y="89" width="100" height="20" uuid="e4e575ea-58a1-4265-b8a5-c5f87fd5ffb0"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PersonaleSala}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="129" width="100" height="20" uuid="b3bf4743-57bf-40c1-a76c-9a698d913ac2"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Fee Sit and Go]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="109" width="100" height="20" uuid="77152629-d503-4538-bcf8-20145dd1c7fe"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Rake Cash]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="434" y="129" width="100" height="20" uuid="22ab44f5-8018-4b89-9828-28c42a30511f"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{GettoneSerata}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="286" y="199" width="100" height="20" uuid="0c60dd9e-9e8d-420b-b78e-9e9293dc4db9"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{VarieNette}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="49" width="70" height="20" uuid="ef320455-0655-468d-9fef-90baa32d652f"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Totale]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="186" y="179" width="100" height="20" uuid="956fe483-2f83-4ccd-a8d0-3235956d15de"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Cavalli]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="186" y="199" width="100" height="20" uuid="9384a4fa-1f2b-49a1-a760-506f34a81cb3"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Cavalli}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="89" width="100" height="20" uuid="191d0457-9e77-451c-8c28-a8eb5ac5fce2"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Rake Torneo]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="149" width="100" height="20" uuid="d4cc169e-dde5-4b14-a367-1f3b5d7ef89d"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Incasso Bar]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="80" y="49" width="219" height="20" uuid="04b67cd1-2598-4c1b-85cf-2b0eaf6bd4c6"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{GuadagnoNettoBarTorneo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="19" width="123" height="30" uuid="c28b3a01-ed69-4214-9254-efee5cdb31ea"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Netto]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="129" width="100" height="20" uuid="e23271f9-96da-43f4-96ba-90b937195c0b"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FeeSitandGo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="109" width="100" height="20" uuid="9d1a535c-ca95-461f-8edd-5a59c2045606"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SpecialSeat}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="89" width="100" height="20" uuid="e552cb13-845a-4e6a-94d2-aceba4dea878"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Rake}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="149" width="100" height="20" uuid="d7ad20f8-b401-4d9f-9296-6653e47ab369"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{IncassoBar}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="51" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="320" height="20" uuid="ced97005-41d9-45c8-9718-774f74400ded"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Note}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="20" width="100" height="20" uuid="8dbf2d56-31de-44eb-a67f-a9cd71d14c38"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Note:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="368" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="168" y="340" width="100" height="20" uuid="7671fca1-5e3f-4bfe-bd9a-8240084c4be0"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Gilet}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="283" width="100" height="20" uuid="82f2d59a-556e-41f9-b02f-6fb5935e8a6f"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Slot3}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="243" width="100" height="20" uuid="daebaf86-dfe4-4b9e-92fe-e4e2d0ee0e3e"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Slot1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="296" y="285" width="131" height="20" uuid="3ba92cb0-808e-4ce3-b3bb-ec64b497a879"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[DD Bar]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="427" y="245" width="125" height="20" uuid="885c6124-12c1-4b65-99d8-110ea7515201"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{GiocoDD}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="168" y="320" width="100" height="20" uuid="91fa8169-a240-41df-a753-759cebe7339e"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Gilet]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="283" width="100" height="20" uuid="4fbfb4d9-e589-44e5-b2d2-aeca37a894f2"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Slot 3]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="296" y="225" width="131" height="20" uuid="6eadc53e-2e32-4120-a2bb-9a0794d6f602"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Spese 4]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="263" width="100" height="20" uuid="4d6416ce-73a6-47fb-a003-517860a007c2"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Slot 2]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="296" y="245" width="131" height="20" uuid="0bbdcdf7-965a-417c-b48b-a57fc250a2c8"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[DD Torneo]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="265" width="100" height="20" uuid="ef78e24f-8f6e-4a2e-b791-f2063d257ff4"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Slot2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="427" y="285" width="125" height="20" uuid="d01172a9-7b15-438a-9612-9fc7244e4fd5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{BarDD}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="268" y="340" width="100" height="20" uuid="8d82e5bb-ba50-4b4c-a5fe-f65d1b078d6d"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{VarieLorde}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="245" width="100" height="20" uuid="0236f767-46d5-4f24-a66d-532b1dc1b0fe"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Slot 1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="268" y="320" width="100" height="20" uuid="ce8496ed-0e57-4126-9b82-6511dbd3f382"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Varie Lorde]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="296" y="265" width="131" height="20" uuid="d94791d1-aea8-41ec-a5b4-2c786dfdd82e"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[DD Cash]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="225" width="100" height="20" uuid="21266b33-8329-41e6-9519-6d15d247ca5b"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Mance}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="427" y="265" width="125" height="20" uuid="03cd9567-b39d-4528-950b-d66e0007d67f"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CashDD}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="427" y="225" width="125" height="20" uuid="9907f731-7ce4-4522-8f0d-403ea474291c"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Spese4}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="225" width="100" height="20" uuid="8b8d80e6-0303-4df0-8b1f-83bdf9c6265f"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Mance]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="146" width="100" height="20" uuid="8dbb6df6-03ce-4633-8178-2c63e0375136"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Rientri Torneo]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="205" width="100" height="20" uuid="9e40a23e-42fa-443b-9842-df3560d60cce"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Tesseramento}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="205" width="100" height="20" uuid="3594a86e-28f6-4056-a613-2ef9fd342416"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Tesseramento]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="126" width="100" height="20" uuid="15ffd9b0-6c0c-4575-b947-bf210e6964ae"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[One Shot]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="165" width="100" height="20" uuid="8073287f-a138-4f0b-ae33-4bc9dcddccf7"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{RientriCash}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="106" width="100" height="20" uuid="0567e038-75d6-483b-a539-ca3928f2b54a"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{EuroClassifica}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="296" y="185" width="131" height="20" uuid="960768a0-62db-4967-afe5-4b549753751e"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Spese 2]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="427" y="126" width="125" height="20" uuid="26975c22-798f-45dc-9e50-f9983ab2bb4f"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MancePagate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="296" y="205" width="131" height="20" uuid="3d819a22-1993-480b-8bdf-0550c3f0a8a6"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Spese 3]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="165" width="100" height="20" uuid="7077d1e6-f43d-4b42-aa43-4178742cabc9"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Rientri Cash]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="427" y="166" width="125" height="20" uuid="2b84d284-13b2-4b00-bd9f-e600ecd702c6"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Spese1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="296" y="106" width="131" height="20" uuid="3e1070e7-0cca-44dd-94ec-6519cb0fcc46"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Euro per Classifica Pagati]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="86" width="70" height="20" uuid="c1cd120f-25b3-440d-a600-60966072140d"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Totale]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="427" y="146" width="125" height="20" uuid="41fff47b-9d5d-4835-91b3-624d4683c25d"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Bollette}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="126" width="100" height="20" uuid="d4fe3ba0-3fbe-488b-b6bf-faeb6b85a69b"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{OneShot}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="427" y="205" width="125" height="20" uuid="e6272074-cb74-48e7-849a-a792db2df254"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Spese3}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="296" y="145" width="131" height="20" uuid="0c76df91-f6d9-4669-a71b-60127683b2fc"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Bollette]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="296" y="165" width="131" height="20" uuid="261c54e0-2ac4-412a-967b-e09753c92b77"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Spese 1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="427" y="185" width="125" height="20" uuid="b163389e-7702-410b-880b-d0aaa2aefbf4"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Spese2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="427" y="106" width="125" height="20" uuid="d590d1f5-92ca-435f-adef-262cc764ec1a"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{EuroClassificaPagati}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="296" y="126" width="131" height="20" uuid="a3a5fac2-25c1-4dfb-9e4b-b78e4bf6972c"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Mance Pagate]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="146" width="100" height="20" uuid="68128d92-ca0d-44ae-b220-ccc27b56722a"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{RientriGioco}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="86" width="150" height="20" uuid="d2e62746-907b-469a-9d70-cc41d73dd910"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{GuadagnoLordo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="185" width="100" height="20" uuid="7da1b0cf-ebaf-4463-9c7b-957fc25db6e4"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Rientri Bar]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="185" width="100" height="20" uuid="2ab51e90-78eb-4e07-8dde-fb77c0abd7ba"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{RientriBar}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="106" width="100" height="20" uuid="5264bd31-105a-4b2f-96e6-2aefb7eabbbe"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Euro per Classifica]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="42" width="123" height="33" uuid="3884042a-2f4d-429c-a55e-4d161aba45e8"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Lordo]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="6" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: My intuition tells me that you have inadvertently created a template which spans onto an _infinite_ number of pages.

Comment: The height of your bands seems more then 830, maybe it can even compile 1 row of detail and it need to switch page...

Comment: The pager after the first are just copies of the first one.  @TimBiegeleisen Can you suggest how to fix? I create it with the visual interface and don't know where to modify in jrxml

Comment: @PetterFriberg have you any suggestion to try?

Comment: Remove summary band height="0", decrease the other band height's, since you are using IReport just make them smaller and check out property "Altezza Band", since your Italian....

Comment: To completly onest I do not understand why you use $F{Gilet} in pageFooter, the $F should be in the detail band (its the rows returned from database), so for me your report is a bit crazy ; ).... Normally in head and footer you use parameters or variables and the $F in detail, so push everything except the title band into detail band...

Comment: I used it in details, and the report did the same in pdf, so I tried moving things.. :)  but it keeps doing that. I used other sections too also in previous versions because details wasn't big enough, and ireport doesn't allow to enlarge beyond a certain height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, it was an error on the sql! simply i didn't joined the tables..